# Difference Between cacheNames and Key in @cachable

Tags: spring, caching, hashmap

I am new to caching and Spring, I can't work out the difference between cacheNames and Key in below example taken from Spring Docs:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames="books", key="#isbn")
public Book findBook(ISBN isbn, boolean checkWarehouse, boolean includeUsed)
```

As I understand cache is simply a key-value pair stored in memory. So in the above example on first invocation the returned Book value will be stored in cache using the value of isbn parameter as key. On subsequent invocations where isbn value is the same as it was first requested the Book stored in cache will be returned. This Book in cache will be found using the Key. So what is cacheNames?

Am I correct in saying cache is stored as key values like this:

```
isbn111111 ---> Book,
isbn122222 ---> Book2,
isbn123333 ---> Book3
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

CacheName is more like group of cache key. When you open this class
`org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheResolver`
you will find this method to find `cache` by `cacheName`

```java
@Override
    public Collection<? extends Cache> resolveCaches(CacheOperationInvocationContext<?> context) {
        Collection<String> cacheNames = getCacheNames(context);
        if (cacheNames == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        Collection<Cache> result = new ArrayList<>(cacheNames.size());
        for (String cacheName : cacheNames) {
            Cache cache = getCacheManager().getCache(cacheName);
            if (cache == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot find cache named '" +
                        cacheName + "' for " + context.getOperation());
            }
            result.add(cache);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

So later in `org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport` spring will get value by cache key from that `cache` object

```java
private Object execute(final CacheOperationInvoker invoker, Method method, CacheOperationContexts contexts) {
        // Special handling of synchronized invocation
        if (contexts.isSynchronized()) {
            CacheOperationContext context = contexts.get(CacheableOperation.class).iterator().next();
            if (isConditionPassing(context, CacheOperationExpressionEvaluator.NO_RESULT)) {
                Object key = generateKey(context, CacheOperationExpressionEvaluator.NO_RESULT);
                Cache cache = context.getCaches().iterator().next();
                try {
                    return wrapCacheValue(method, cache.get(key, () -> unwrapReturnValue(invokeOperation(invoker))));
                }
                catch (Cache.ValueRetrievalException ex) {
                    // The invoker wraps any Throwable in a ThrowableWrapper instance so we
                    // can just make sure that one bubbles up the stack.
                    throw (CacheOperationInvoker.ThrowableWrapper) ex.getCause();
                }
            }
//...other logic
```

Answer (score 0):

The cacheNames are the names of the caches itself, where the data is stored. You can have multiple caches, e.g. for different entity types different caches, or depending on replication needs etc.

Comment: Thanks - Key is used to retrieve the value stored in cache so why is cacheNames or having more than one cache relevant?

Answer (score 0):

One significance of cacheNames would be helping with default key generation for @Cacheable used when explicit keys aren't passed to method. Its very unclear from Spring documentation on what would be seriously wrong or inaccurate if cacheNames is not supplied at Class level or Method level when using Spring Cache.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CacheConfig.html#cacheNames--